# Laravel - Include assets on Middleware Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Inside my app, exist a route group called `admin`, any route inside this group call two resources: `public/css/admin.css` and `public/js/admin.js`, but any unauthenticated user has access to these files. How can I include these files inside the Auth Middleware?

My admin routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\IndexController@index')->name('panel');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function() {});

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'settings'], function() {});

    Route::fallback('Admin\ExceptionController@exception');
});
```

My resources links:

```
http://localhost:3000/css/admin.css
http://localhost:3000/js/admin.js
```

My resources links should be:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/css/admin.css
http://localhost:3000/admin/js/admin.js
```

If I just create the folder `admin` inside the `public` folder I just got a 403 error...

What can I do about it?

Comment: Could you `require('/off-camera/admin/js/admin.js')` and `admin.css` in your admin "master page" view (or load them `if ($admin) = true`) so they're loaded inline, so to speak? You could keep them in any directory not /public.

Comment: why don't you make a route for them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Now we'll use **storage** instead of **public** directory.

Although I agree that you should not have any sensitive info in your css/js files but if you really want to serve the files to authenticated users you can do it with this work around.

**NOTE:** I have made the project publicaly avaiable on git so you can clone from there if you want. [Git Repo](https://github.com/alyjee/stack)

1. Create a directory for admin assets with permission `755`
2. Create a helper function to serve admin assets.
3. Make the helper function available in blade.
4. Link the assets using the helper function in order to first authenticate and then serve the file.

**Basic Idea**:

- The basic idea is to have a directory which no one can access via
  browser.
- Authenticate the user
- Copy the files from protected directory.
- Paste the files in a new directory (**in storage**) only associated with the authenticated user.
- Delete the associated directory on user logout.

**Implementation**:

1. Created a directory called `admin_assets` in **public** directory.
2. Change the permission of the directory to `755`.
3. Created a helper class named `CommonHelper`, and write functions to **serve** and **delete** admin assets.
4. Served the assets with these helper functions as following:

`<link  href="{{ asset( CommonHelper::serveAdminAssets('app.css', '/css/') ) }}"  rel="stylesheet">`

5. Deleted the files at logout.

**Finally**, as far as the user is logged in the files will be available for him/her, all files will be deleted from the folder once the user logs out.

**CommonHelper** class:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 */
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class CommonHelper {
  public static function serveAdminAssets($fileName, $filePath) {

    if( Auth::check() ) {
      $adminAssetsBasePath = public_path().'/admin_assets';

      $source = $adminAssetsBasePath.$filePath.$fileName;

      $destDir = 'public/'.Auth::user()->id.$filePath;

      $dest = $destDir.$fileName;

      Storage::put($dest, file_get_contents($source));

      return Storage::url($dest);
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  public static function removeAdminAssets($id) {

      $destDir = storage_path('app/public/'.Auth::user()->id);
      File::cleanDirectory($destDir);
      File::deleteDirectory($destDir);
  }
}
 ?>
```

**Notes:**

1. > Remember, if you are using the local driver, all files that should be
   >   publicly accessible should be placed in the storage/app/public
   >   directory. Furthermore, you should create a symbolic link at
   >   public/storage which points to the  storage/app/public directory. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem)
2. > Before deleting a directory you should empty it first.

Comment: Your solution would sounds better if could add the files to the storage folder

Comment: yes, it would be better to create the files (admin assets) somewhere in storage folder.

Comment: May u please edit your answer for a more complete reference?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you are using it because you don't want unauthenticated users to know the contents of these css/js files.
You shouldn't have any sensitive information in your css/js files, so there is no problem on serving them.

Otherwise, if you want to limit access to a file you should make the file download through PHP. For example you could have the file outside you public folder and make it conditional downloadable through a method that gets file contents and serves for download.

You should can make that public admin folder though, check file permissions and file ownership.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that you can apply.

Store your assets in `storage` directory.

then you can check whether it is an admin or Not.

In your view you can u can inject the Admin Assets Like.

```
<script>
  {!! \Storage::disk('urdisk name')->get('admin.js'); !!}
</script>
```

for your css you can

```
 <style>
  {!! \Storage::disk('urdisk name')->get('admin.css'); !!}
</style>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For applying `auth` to the asset files you need to go through from the laravel, not by accessing the files using **full path**, you need to access css/js files via route so that laravel will be able to apply auth on each files inside route group.

**P.S** Files must be saved inside **storage** folder, i-e `storage/admin.css`

**Updated route group**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

Route::get('/', 'Admin\IndexController@index')->name('panel');

Route::get('{file}', 'StaticFileController@serveFile');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function() {});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'settings'], function() {});

Route::fallback('Admin\ExceptionController@exception');
});
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Use Response;

use App\Http\Requests;

class StaticFileController extends Controller
{
    public function serveFile ($file)
    {

        $storagePath = storage_path($file);
        $mimeType = mime_content_type($storagePath);
        if( ! \File::exists($storagePath)){
            return view('errorpages.404');
        }
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => $mimeType,
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$file.'"'
        );
        return Response::make(file_get_contents($storagePath), 200, $headers);

    }
}
```

Now your resources links would be

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/css/admin.css
http://localhost:3000/admin/js/admin.js
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For blade templates you can use the `@auth` directive.

When you're including these files in your blade templates, you can wrap the script tag in an `@auth` directive and they'll only be rendered when the user is authenticated.

E.g.

```
@auth

<script src="{{ asset('path/to/your/js') }}"></script>

@endauth
```

There's also an optional parameter that allows you to set the guard you want to check for e.g. `@auth('your-guard')`.

It's available in Laravel 5.5+

[Here's the documentation for a better overview of its use.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#authentication-directives)